# Why does putInt require a string in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with SharedPreferences but I have a problem.
In one class I have:

```
protected static String someValue;

int myValue = 10;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(someValue, myValue);
editor.commit();
```

How can I retrieve this in another class?

```
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(WHAT DO I TYPE HERE?), myNewHighScore)
```

Comment: the string is the key for the value, like "age" = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting the SharedPreference, you have to do it like

```
editor.putInt("your_key", myValue);
```

You can retrieve it like,

```
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt("your_key", default_score);
```

When you use `getInt()` then you have to return a default integer value, if the value is not set earlier in shared preference.

Comment: Thank you but how do I know if the value was set earlier?

Comment: If the value was set earlier, then the getInt() would return the value that was entered earlier. The default value will only be returned if there is no previously entered value.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences stores the values using key/value pairs much like regular HashMaps, and that is what that string is, the key.

The key should be unique for each Preference you store, and preferably, should be put in the strings.xml file.

For more information, check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs

Answer (score 1):

if you use this.getPreferences to get a instance, this instance is just included and could be used in this class. And if you want to share the SharedPreference in another class, you can do like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

In this way, you can get  SharedPreferences in another class.